# why don't we store react common components like button in localstorage , if done so then we wont need to get them again

Tags: reactjs, components, local-storage

what i say is that in most websites we use a component library and the pages are mostly the combination of these components combined to form bigger components and then pages.
what if we had these components' function definitions cached in local storage, in this way we have our whole component library in local storage and we can get them and render them

```
    function App() {
//generic common component Primary Input (say it can also come from our UI component Library)
      const InputPrimary = ({ val }) => <div style={{ color: "blue" }}>{val}</div>;
    // set the function definition in local storage once
      localStorage.setItem("InputPrimary", InputPrimary);
//get the definition as many times as you need in O(1) from local storage 
      const InputPrimaryLocalComp = eval(
        "(" + localStorage.getItem("InputPrimary") + ")"
      );
      return (
        <div className="App">
// render the component using function definition that we get from local storage
          {InputPrimaryLocalComp && <InputPrimaryLocalComp val="123" />}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that creating a function the normal way is a performance bottleneck? PS, don't create a new type of component in the middle of rendering App. Create it just once, outside of App.

Comment: don't create a new type of component in the middle of rendering App-> this above code is just for test purpose , dont treat it as a prod. code